# CGAffineTransform from NSString

Tags: macos, cocoa, cgaffinetransform

How can I obtain a `CGAffineTransform` from a `NSString` in Cocoa?

On iOS there is `CGAffineTransformFromString`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For lack of a better solution I'm currently doing this:

```
CGAffineTransform CGAffineTransformFromString(NSString *string)
{
    string = [string stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"[ ]"]];
    NSArray *components = [string componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
    CGAffineTransform transform;
    transform.a = [[components objectAtIndex:0] floatValue];
    transform.b = [[components objectAtIndex:1] floatValue];
    transform.c = [[components objectAtIndex:2] floatValue];
    transform.d = [[components objectAtIndex:3] floatValue];
    transform.tx = [[components objectAtIndex:4] floatValue];
    transform.ty = [[components objectAtIndex:5] floatValue];
    return transform;
}
```